# Modify scraping script in PHP to download scraped files or images

Tags: php, image, file, dom, web-scraping

Guys, I got a small problem and need some help.I got a PHP script which scrapes a domain for images and outputs the image links right now. My problem is I need to output the images as image elements and download automatically all scraped images or files to the server. Any suggestions would be great this I got so far right now.

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://example.com/gallery/1/');
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
  echo $image->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Comment: Just add an `<img>` tag? change `echo $image->getAttribute('src');` to `echo "<img src='{$image->getAttribute('src')}'>";`

Comment: Thx man was blind in a wood full of trees didnt thought that it would be that easy expected something difficult. Thx by the way how to download all images on button click?

Comment: Well this one is not easy to do on your own you can have separate links per image but having single button for all image will be very difficult i would suggest better try some browser extension for that